# Relationship to itself in Realm swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, realm

I'm having a Recipe Model as shown in image (Recipe Model). I'm calling two apis, one which will return all the recipes and the other which return only the favorite recipes. Because favorites are nothing but recipes I want to add a relation in the Recipe model itself as "favorites". So, I want to get all the favorites recipes by calling "recipe.favorites" on the model. How can I achieve this?

The problem I face now is if I assign a recipe to recipe.favorite = recipe it will infinitely assign it and I get Max limit exceeded.

Please see the two images attached to get to more idea.

I'm using **RealmSwift** 0.100. Please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

[Recipe Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORGsC.png)
[Response Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9uX1.png)

[image: Recipe Model]
[image: Response Model]